# Running Python scripts in Linux/UNIX sequentially

Tags: python, linux, unix, thread-safety, python-multithreading

I have developed code that deletes all the files in a folder. I want it to be only able to run concurrently. Meaning, if another user tries to run the script while it is running, the user will get a message saying that the script is already running as to avoid errors in the process.

I tried using `threading.Lock()`, `acquire()` and `release()` but it's not doing any good.

This is my code:

```
def delete_files(ini_path, days_num):
   config = read_config_file(ini_path)
   try:
      lock.acquire()                                   
      log_processes(str(config[1]))
      if os.listdir(str(config[0])) == []:
          print("Empty list")
      else:
          print("List loaded")
      for file in os.listdir(str(config[0])):      
          file_path = config[0] + '/' + file
          file_datestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file_path))
          start_of_deletion_date = date.today() - timedelta(days = int(days_num))
          if date.today() > file_datestamp.date() and file_datestamp.date() >= start_of_deletion_date:
              if not os.path.isdir(file_path):
                os.remove(str(file_path))
          else:
              if not os.path.isdir(file_path):
                compress_file(str(file_path))
      lock.release()    
    except Exception as e:
        log_processes(config[1], e)
        print(e)
```

When I tried to run it simultaneously, I get this error:

```
"ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
```

because the file has already been deleted by the first run.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Copy&paste both your code and the output to the question. Maybe it would be better to ignore the error when the file no longer exists than trying to block concurrent execution. When you run `rm *` in the same directory in two shells at the same time I would expect errors as well.

Comment: Hi @Bodo, I did not a rm *. I run the script which contains the codes above. Btw thanks for the warning.

Comment: Sure, but the problem is the same. The script reads directory entries and removes files (with additional conditions). When you run `rm *`, the shell reads directory entries and passes the file names to `rm` which removes the files. In both cases, when you run two instances of the program/command at the same time, one instance might want to remove (or check) a file that has already been removed by the other instance. My point is that instead of throwing an error in case of a non-existant file you could treat this situation as success because the desired result "file removed" is already achieved

Comment: My idea is to catch `FileNotFoundError` inside the loop and treat this as success. I would not lock the whole loop but only individual `os.remove(str(file_path))` and `compress_file(str(file_path))`. When running two instances at the same time they will probably read a slightly different time which might lead to compressing the file in one instance and removing the file in the other. You should call e.g. `now = date.today()` and `start_of_deletion_date = now - timedelta(...)` only once before the loop and later compare with these variables to use the same time for all files.